# Inheritance hierarchy design approach - Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototyping

For the below code, that creates inheritance hierarchy,

```
function Animal(){
    this.name = "Animal";

    // toString is a function in the main Object that every
    // object inherits from
    this.toString = function() {
        return "My name is : " + this.name;
    };
}


function Rodent(){
   this.name = "Rodent";
}

function Rat(){
  this.name = "Rat";
}

Rodent.prototype = new Animal();
Rat.prototype = new Rodent();

Rodent.prototype.constructor = Rodent;
Rat.prototype.constructor = Rat;

var caneRat = new Rat();

document.write(caneRat.toString() + "<br />");
```

a little modification is done by completely replacing `Rat.prototype` with `Rodent.prototype`, as a second approach, shown below,

```
function Animal(){
    this.name = "Animal";

    // toString is a function in the main Object that every
    // object inherits from
    this.toString = function() {
        return "My name is : " + this.name;
    };
}


function Rodent(){
   this.name = "Rodent";
}

function Rat(){
  this.name = "Rat";
}

Rodent.prototype = new Animal();
Rat.prototype = Rodent.prototype;
Rodent.prototype.constructor = Rodent;

var caneRat = new Rat();

document.write(caneRat.toString() + "<br />");
```

What are the advantages & disadvantages in the second approach of inheritance hierarchy design compared to first approach? Second approach is visualized as shown below..

[image]

Comment: @Bergi Is this the wrong approach in designing inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. `Rat` and `Rodent` don't inherit from each other.

Comment: @Bergi How do I recorrect this code?

Comment: Your first attempt seemed better, although you [should not use `new` at all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) for creating prototype objects.

Comment: @Bergi Can you please share the code without a `new` keyword for prototype objects for first approach?

Comment: Just apply the answer of the linked question to your code. I'm sure you can do that. I might even have another look whether you got it right.

Comment: @Bergi Is this [code](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/html/dummy.html) fine? look up process will be slow, when you say, `arcticWolf.toString();`

Comment: You also need [some kind of "super call"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10898859/1048572) so that all Animal instances get that `toString` method (if you don't want to just put it on the `Animal.prototype`)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I placed it on `Animal.prototype` now. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/html/dummy.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally fairly awkward and error-prone to implement "classical inheritance" in JavaScript.  Instead, try working *with* the language and use behavior delegation:

```
var Animal = {
  setName: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },

  sayName: function() {
    return 'My name is: ' + this.name;
  }
};

var Rodent = Object.create(Animal);
var Rat = Object.create(Rodent);
var caneRat = Object.create(Rat);

caneRat.setName('Rat');

console.log(caneRat.sayName()); // 'My name is Rat'
```

You'll probably find that you can eliminate a lot of your "subclasses" with this approach.

For more detail on prototypes in JavaScript, take a look at [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md).

Also, try to avoid overwriting native object methods (e.g. `toString`) unless you have a really good reason to do so.